# How would I find the second largest salary using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How would I go about querying for the second largest salary from all employees in my Employee table? in MySQL

Comment: You can not an interview question here which is asked to you , without google

Comment: What about ties? I.e. if there are two (or more) with the same max salary.

Comment: `order by salary desc limit 1,1`

Comment: You could use a query

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this, It should must work.

```
SELECT name, salary
FROM employees
WHERE salary = (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employees WHERE salary < (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employees))
```

Or you can try this one as well.

```
/* looking for 2nd highest salary -- notice the '=2' */
SELECT name,salary FROM employees
WHERE salary = (SELECT DISTINCT(salary) FROM employees as e1
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(salary))=2 FROM employees as e2
WHERE e1.salary <= e2.salary)) ORDER BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

Order by salary descending, then use `LIMIT`:

```
select *
from employees
order by salary desc
limit 1,1
```

The first 1 means to skip the first row, the second 1 means return one row.

Answer (score -1):

You can try below -

```
  select name, max(salary) from employee where salary < (select max(salary) from employee)
    group by name;
```